# Java repaint method does not work when called from another class

Tags: java, swing, methods, repaint

I have been coding up Java with Netbeans for about a year now, and have written a lot of data manipulation code which plots graphs on-screen. I generally plant a JPanel object in my main window, write custom painting code, and call the repaint() method as needed.

But today, for the first time, I tried to invoke a repaint on a panel from a class (object) other than the one that contained the panel.  Although the compiler found nothing wrong with this, and in debugging mode, it single-stepped properly to the exterior call to the repaint, no repaint actually occurred, and the code did not actually step into the repaint method.

I wrote a minimalist program to demonstrate the problem, as shown below (Main is ommitted, since it only contains code to set up the two on-screen panels.)

--- Description of classes, first contains the drawing surface, other the repaint call ---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Panel1 extends JComponent
{
   GraphPnl graphPnl;
   boolean colorFlag;

   public Panel1()
   {
     setLayout(null);
     colorFlag = true;

     graphPnl = new GraphPnl();
     graphPnl.setBounds(10, 10, 110, 110);
     graphPnl.setBackground(Color.black);
     add(graphPnl);

}//Panel1()

public class GraphPnl extends JPanel
{
  //just draws a line segment, toggling color

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
      super.paint(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      if (colorFlag) {g2.setColor(Color.red);} else {g2.setColor(Color.green);}
      g2.drawLine(10, 10, 50, 50);
   }//paint
 }//GraphPnl
}//Panel1

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Panel2 extends JComponent
{
   JButton testBtn;
   TestAction testAction;
   Panel1 p1;

   public Panel2()
   {
      p1 = new Panel1();
      testBtn = new JButton("Click");
      testBtn.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 30);
      add(testBtn);
      testAction = new TestAction();
      testBtn.addActionListener(testAction);
   }//Panel2()


   public class TestAction implements ActionListener
   {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
     {
       p1.colorFlag = ! p1.colorFlag;
       p1.graphPnl.repaint();
     }
   }//TestAction
}//Panel2
```

If anyone has any insights into this, or knows of a workaround, I'd be very happy to hear
from you.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

John Doner

Comment: Of course the repaint() method of window 1 will function while window 2 has focus. Multiple threads has nothing to do with this and is in fact the complete opposite of what you want. All Swing updates should be done on the EDT. Your comments in the answer you accepted makes no sense. The other answers provided gave you the real solution to your problem (based on the limited code you provided since you have yet to post your SSCCE). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when you are painting a JComponent, the clip region is set to that JComponent. So if other components try to paint (or if you call their repaint), they won't, because of the clipping.

Comment: I think you probably got it right.  I tried reworking the simple example in terms of the above answers, and got the same result.  So it appears that if you create two separate windows on-screen, the repaint methods for window 1 will not fucntion if invoked while window 2 has focus.  Perhaps there is a way around this by using multiple threads, which I'll pursue.

Comment: I recommend against going the multi-threaded approach, as Swing is largely not multi-threaded. Instead, you should probably investigate the concept of dirty regions. Each window should note when portions of its window become dirty. You should then let the repaint mechanisms be called automatically. See http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

"Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

> `main` is ommitted, since it only contains code to set up the two on-screen panels.

Verify that you construct your GUI on the EDT, as shown in the article [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Addendum: Here's an example showing both principles:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282159 */
public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

    private boolean colorFlag;

    public GraphPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    }

    public void toggle() {
        colorFlag = !colorFlag;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        if (colorFlag) {
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
        } else {
            g2.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("GraphPanel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(new ControlPanel(this), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GraphPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

    public ControlPanel(final GraphPanel gp) {
        this.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Click") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gp.toggle();
                gp.repaint();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Addendum: As noted in @camickr's comment, [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) may help guide your layout selection.

Comment: +1, for the example and tutorial link. Now the poster can also read up on using layout managers and I don't have to post the link :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Main is ommitted, since it only contains code to set up the two on-screen panels.)

Well, by definition when you have a problem you don't know what code is or isn't relative until the problem is solved. So a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) should be posted.

As a wild guess I would say your component has a size of 0 so there is nothing to paint.

> I generally plant a JPanel object in my main window, write custom painting code, and call the repaint() method as needed

You probably got lucky because you added the panel to the center of a BorderLayout which automatically gives the panel all the space available to the frame.

trashgod's example shows one way to set the preferred size of a custom component. Another way is to override the getPreferredSize() method to return the proper value.

You really should learn how to use layout manager rather than using null layouts and you will avoid problems like this in the future. There is no need to use a null layout unless you have a drag/drop type of application.

Comment: I happen to like the null layout process.  I create a lot of very custom GUI's and I tried the various layouts for awhile, but I can now produce a very complex interface in an hour or so, and if I ever want to change it, I can squeeze move things around exactly as I see fit.  In my opinion, Swing layouts are the weakest part of Java.

Comment: That is what all newbies think because they don't understand layout managers. It only takes me minutes to create a complex interface, not hours. Besides programming isn't about how long it take so create the code, its about maintaining the code and layout managers make it easier for the next person. For example if you have a row of 10 components and you need to add a component at the start. If you use a FlowLayout it is a single line of code. Using a null layout you need to adjust the bounds of the original 10 components because they are now shifted right.